# How can I ignore specifically annotated classes under TestNG?

Tags: java, annotations, testng

Goal: Ignore test classes on runtime which have custom annotation set.

What I tried:

```
 public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
          if (context instanceof TestRunner) {
                 Map<Class<?>, ITestClass> notSkippedCl  = new HashMap<Class<?>, ITestClass>();
                 TestRunner tRunner = (TestRunner) context;
                 Collection<ITestClass> testClasses = tRunner.getTestClasses();
              for (Iterator<ITestClass> iterator = testClasses.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                       ITestClass rr = iterator.next();
                       Class<?> realClass = rr.getRealClass();

                       if (chechAnnotation(realClass))
                       {
                              notSkippedCl.put(realClass,rr);
                       }
                 }

                 try {

                       Field field = TestRunner.class.getDeclaredField("m_classMap");
                       field.setAccessible(true);
                       Map<Class<?>, ITestClass> mapClass = (Map<Class<?>, ITestClass>) field.get(tRunner);
                       mapClass.clear();
                       mapClass.putAll(notSkippedCl);

                 } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (SecurityException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }

          }

   }
```

`onStart` method is called before all test classes in package, So I get TestRunner here, which contains map of all test classes. I iterate throw each one, checking it Annotation and if I find one I add to new map. Then I override map of TestRunner. I was thinking that this will help me ignore classes without annotation, but I was wrong.

Maybe someone knows right solution, to Ignore  test classes depending on custom annotation?
(parameter of the method cannot be changed)

P.S. setting `@Test(enabled=false)` annotation is not a solution in my situation

**--EDIT_FAUND_SOLUTION--**

I managed to create solution, not sure if there was easier way, but this works:

```
@Override
public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    if (context instanceof TestRunner) {
        Set<ITestNGMethod> methodstodo = new HashSet<ITestNGMethod>();
        TestRunner tRunner = (TestRunner) context;
        ITestNGMethod[] allTestMethods = tRunner.getAllTestMethods();
        SupportedBrowser currentBrowser = HelperMethod.getCurrentBrowser();
        for(ITestNGMethod testMethod : allTestMethods)
        {
            Class<?> realClass = testMethod.getTestClass().getRealClass();
            Set<SupportedBrowser> classBrowsers = getBrowsers(realClass);

            if (classBrowsers.contains(currentBrowser)) {
                methodstodo.add(testMethod);
            }
        }

         try {
         Field field = TestRunner.class.getDeclaredField("m_allTestMethods");
         field.setAccessible(true);
         field.set(tRunner, methodstodo.toArray(new ITestNGMethod[methodstodo.size()]));
         } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to create `org.testng.IMethodInterceptor` as a Listener. TestNG calls `intercept` method just before test suite starts. You get list of all methods as a parameter and have to return modified/new/etc. list with methods you want to run. See documentation http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors for more details and examples.